# php - CakePHP controller action not firing

Tags: cakephp, controller, routes

actions in PagesController is not firing bt when i'm commenting any action it shows error message. UsersController is working perfectly. Don't know what is the problem. no problem with routes.php. Basically I'm takingthe project from a previous team. All actions in all controller except UsersCOntroller redirecting to home page. 
This is my PagesController :

```
App::uses('AppController', 'Controller'); class PagesController extends AppController { public function aboutus() { echo "test"; die; } }
```

This is my UsersController :

```
class UsersController extends AppController { public function faq() { echo "test"; die; } }
```

This is Route file

```
Router::connect('/about', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'aboutus')); Router::connect('/faq', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'faq'));
```

Here users controller working perfectly.

Please help

Comment: There are tons of possibilities for what could be wrong, however you have given us very little information to look at.  I'd suggest reformatting your question to make it more readable and provide more information.

Comment: Updated my question please look at it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using Auth component in your AppController? In that case, you need to specify auth allow in the beforeFilter function:

```
public function beforeFilter() {

  /* Other code... */

   $this->Auth->allow(array("faq", "about")); // Add this

}
```

Hope this helps.

Peace! xD

Comment: Thank you Obhect Manipulator, you saved my day

Comment: Using $this->Auth->allow("*"); this also same right?

Comment: You're welcome, bud! :)  $this->Auth->allow("*"); will enable all actions without the need to log in. It can actually be a security threat. I'd suggest you to follow  $this->Auth->allow(array("faq", "about")); -> this way. So that you can specify the actions that can be performed without logging in.